# Using descriptor class to raise RuntimeError when user tries to change object's value

Tags: python, descriptor

I have written a Circle class using descriptors that allows the user to set the values for x, y and r of a circle and checks if the values for x and y are integers. If the user inputs a non integer number, then a TypeError is raised, now I want to make another descriptor class that allows a user to get the value for the area and circumference of the circle, but not be able to set it. I think I have the `__get__` method working correct, but the `__set__` method isn't.

```
class Integer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name        # stores name of the managed object's attribute

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError('Expected an int')
        else:
            instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
class Computations(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name   # default value for area, circumference, distance to origin

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            print('this is the __get__ if statement running')
            return self
        else:
            print('this is the __get__ else statement running')
            return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            raise RuntimeError('Cant set formulas')
        else:
            instance.__dict__[self.name] = value


class Circle:
    x = Integer('_x')   # Use _x and _y as the __dict__ key of a Point
    y = Integer('_y')   # These will be the storage names for a Point
    r = Integer('_r')

    area = Computations('_area')   # class variable of Computations
    circumference = Computations('_circumference')
    distance_to_origin = Computations('_distance_to_origin')

    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self.x = x      # invokes Integer.x.__set__
        self.y = y      # invokes Integer.y.__set__
        self.r = r      # for radius/invokes Integer.r.
        self.area = pi * self.r * self.r
        self.circumference = 2 * pi * self.r
        self.distance_to_origin = abs(sqrt((self.x - 0)*(self.x - 0) + (self.y - 0) * (self.y - 0)) - self.r)


# Testing code
if __name__ == '__main__':

    circle = Circle(x=3, y=4, r=5)
    print(circle.x)
    print(circle.y)
    print(circle.r)
    print(circle.area)
   # circle.area = 12
    print(circle.area)
    print(circle.circumference)
    print(circle.distance_to_origin)
    tests = [('circle.x = 12.3', "print('Setting circle.x to non-integer fails')"),
             ('circle.y = 23.4', "print('Setting circle.y to non-integer fails')"),
             ('circle.area = 23.4', "print('Setting circle.area fails')"),
             ('circle.circumference = 23.4', "print('Setting circle.circumference fails')"),
             ('circle.distance_to_origin = 23.4', "print('Setting circle.distance_to_origin fails')"),
             ('circle.z = 5.6', "print('Setting circle.z fails')"),
             ('print(circle.z)', "print('Printing circle.z fails')")]
    for test in tests:
        try:
            exec(test[0])
        except:
            exec(test[1])
```

The program runs, but it allows area, circumference and distance_to_origin to be set, which isn't what I want it to do. I know that the line `"if isinstance(value, int): raise RuntimeError('Can't set formulas')"` means that if the value that the user puts is not an integer than it raises an error. I'm just not sure what to put in place of it so that it throws an error and doesn't allow the user to change the value.

The correct output of the testing code is as follows:

```
78.53981633974483
31.41592653589793
0.0
Setting circle.x to non-integer fails
Setting circle.y to non-integer fails
Setting circle.area fails
Setting circle.circumference fails
Setting circle.distance_to_origin fails
5.6
```

Comment: I guess because `self.area` is not `Circle. area`. BTW have you considered using `__setattr__`?

Comment: @Pynchia Are you talking about in the Circle Class? I changed it so Circle.area, etc and it doesn't print the print statement of the __get__ method, and still allows the user to manually input the value. Yes I know I can use __setattr__, I have this circle class written using properties, using __getattr__/__setattr__ and then this one using descriptors.

Comment: I never said to use `Circle.area` instead. I said they aren't the same thing. I ignore why you use class attributes at all. From your description and code you require instance attributes

Comment: @Pynchia isn't self.area already an instance attribute though?

Comment: On which are you using `Computations`?

Comment: @Pynchia I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking but I'm using a separate descriptor class (Computations) to be able to get the value for area, etc, but not allow the user to manually set it. For instance, the variables x, y and r can be user defined and x and y are restricted to be integers, otherwise it won't set. I'm trying to do the same thing with area, etc except setting it to any value will fail and raise a RunTime error. I'll try to add the descriptor class Integer to show what it's doing for x and y as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Improved descriptor Computation

This would allow only the initial setting of a `Computations` descriptor:

```
class Computations(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name   # default value for area, circumference, distance to origin

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            print('this is the __get__ if statement running')
            return self
        else:
            print('this is the __get__ else statement running')
            return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if hasattr(instance, self.name + '_is_set'):
            raise ValueError('Cannot set {} again.'.format(self.name[1:]))
        if isinstance(value, int):
            raise RuntimeError('Cant set formulas')
        else:
            instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
            setattr(instance, self.name + '_is_set', True)
```

The trick is to generate a new attribute on the instance:

```
setattr(instance, self.name + '_is_set', True)
```

For the instance `circle` and the attribute `circumference` this means:

```
circle._circumference_is_set = True
```

This checks if this attribute exists:

```
if hasattr(instance, self.name + '_is_set')
```

Again for our case this means:

```
if hasattr(circle, '_circumference_is_set')
```

The first time `__set__` is called for `circumference` is in the class `Circle`:

```
self.circumference = 2 * pi * self.r
```

Now `_circumference_is_set` exists and the next try to set it will result in an exception.

### Putting it all together

Your code with my new descriptor `Computation`:

```
from math import pi, sqrt

class Integer(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name        # stores name of the managed object's attribute

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError('Expected an int')
        else:
            instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

class Computations(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name   # default value for area, circumference, distance to origin

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is None:
            print('this is the __get__ if statement running')
            return self
        else:
            print('this is the __get__ else statement running')
            return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if hasattr(instance, self.name + 'is_set'):
            raise ValueError('Cannot set {} again.'.format(self.name[1:]))
        if isinstance(value, int):
            raise RuntimeError('Cant set formulas')
        else:
            instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
            setattr(instance, self.name + 'is_set', True)


class Circle(object):
    x = Integer('_x')   # Use _x and _y as the __dict__ key of a Point
    y = Integer('_y')   # These will be the storage names for a Point
    r = Integer('_r')

    area = Computations('_area')   # class variable of Computations
    circumference = Computations('_circumference')
    distance_to_origin = Computations('_distance_to_origin')

    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self.x = x      # invokes Integer.x.__set__
        self.y = y      # invokes Integer.y.__set__
        self.r = r      # for radius/invokes Integer.r.
        self.area = pi * self.r * self.r
        self.circumference = 2 * pi * self.r
        self.distance_to_origin = abs(sqrt(self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y) - self.r)
```

### Testing

Now trying to set `circle.circumference` raises an exception:

```
# Testing code
if __name__ == '__main__':

    circle = Circle(x=3, y=4, r=5)
    print('circumference', circle.circumference)

    print('try setting circumference')
    circle.circumference = 12.5
```

Output:

```
this is the __get__ else statement running
circumference 31.41592653589793
try setting circumference

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-227-316199bab738> in <module>()
     64 
     65     print('try setting circumference')
---> 66     circle.circumference = 12.5

<ipython-input-227-316199bab738> in __set__(self, instance, value)
     31     def __set__(self, instance, value):
     32         if hasattr(instance, self.name + 'is_set'):
---> 33             raise ValueError('Cannot set {} again.'.format(self.name[1:]))
     34         if isinstance(value, int):
     35             raise RuntimeError('Cant set formulas')

ValueError: Cannot set circumference again.
```

Your tests:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    circle = Circle(x=3, y=4, r=5)
    print(circle.x)
    print(circle.y)
    print(circle.r)
    print(circle.area)
   # circle.area = 12
    print(circle.area)
    print(circle.circumference)
    print(circle.distance_to_origin)
    tests = [('circle.x = 12.3', "print('Setting circle.x to non-integer fails')"),
             ('circle.y = 23.4', "print('Setting circle.y to non-integer fails')"),
             ('circle.area = 23.4', "print('Setting circle.area fails')"),
             ('circle.circumference = 23.4', "print('Setting circle.circumference fails')"),
             ('circle.distance_to_origin = 23.4', "print('Setting circle.distance_to_origin fails')"),
             ('circle.z = 5.6', "print('Setting circle.z fails')"),
             ('print(circle.z)', "print('Printing circle.z fails')")]
    for test in tests:
        try:
            exec(test[0])
        except:
            exec(test[1])
```

generate this output:

```
3
4
5
this is the __get__ else statement running
78.53981633974483
this is the __get__ else statement running
78.53981633974483
this is the __get__ else statement running
31.41592653589793
this is the __get__ else statement running
0.0
Setting circle.x to non-integer fails
Setting circle.y to non-integer fails
Setting circle.area fails
Setting circle.circumference fails
Setting circle.distance_to_origin fails
5.6
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what your setter is doing now, from what I'm understanding is that the user could still set area, etc as a float and it would still be valid which isn't what I would like it to do. Unless I'm not fully understanding your code.

Comment: Added a description and a test. Try if works for your use case.

Comment: I tried it again and the description makes sense and was very helpful, but it still doesn't run properly. The code only allows the user to not set area, circumference, etc as an int, but it's perfectly fine for them to change it's value to a float. I ran the code, but when I set circle.area = 12.9 no errors are thrown. I don't want the user to be able to set any of those values at all.

Comment: I'm gonna edit my original code to show the output that it's supposed to have (ie the one that occurs when I use properties for the circle class.) This edited code doesn't print out the lines "Setting circle.area fails, etc" and when I set the value to a non integer number it passes which it isn't supposed to do

Comment: Added the output. Looks a lot like what you want. Plus some extra debug prints.

Comment: For some reason, I'm not getting it to properly print out. Everything is the same, but on mine it will allow a floating point number to be set for area, circumference, distance_to_origin, but raises the error if it's set as an int. I believe it's the `if isinstance(value, int): raise RuntimeError` line.

Comment: I work with Python 3.5. When you work with Python 2, all classes need to inherit from `object`. Updated my code.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4 and I'm still not getting the correct output. Should I update the code from my original question for you to see?

Comment: Use the code I posted in my answer under *Putting it all together*  and add your tests. Works with Python 3.4. Make sure you run the right program.

Comment: everything looks exactly the same but when I run mine it allows area, etc to be set, but when I copy and pasted your code it works as it's supposed to. I even had someone else look at both codes so I'm not sure what the problem was/is. However, thank you for your help and taking the time to explain everything to me!

Answer (score 0):

### Does not work correctly with floats

Your `__set__` function currently allows setting a value, as long as it is not integer:

```
def __set__(self, instance, value):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        raise RuntimeError('Cant set formulas')
    else:
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
```

Then, you are setting the `circumference` to a float value, both in the class itself and in the test, so it passes:

```
self.circumference = 2 * pi * self.r
```

and:

```
circle.circumference = 23.4
```

However, setting an integer value would fail:

```
circle.circumference = 10

--> RuntimeError: Cant set formulas
```

### Fix the `__set__`

To fix that problem, you can make `__set__` fail always:

```
def __set__(self, instance, value):
    raise RuntimeError('Cant set formulas')
```

You still want the circumference to be writeable from within the class, but for that, you can use the *private*`_circumference`:

```
self._area = pi * self.r * self.r
self._circumference = 2 * pi * self.r
self._distance_to_origin = abs(sqrt((self.x - 0)*(self.x - 0) + (self.y - 0) * (self.y - 0)) - self.r)
```

### Much simpler solution

The above fix is just theoretical, to show it can be fixed. It is usually much simpler to use `property` for providing custom getters and setters:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    ...
    self._circumference = 2 * pi * self.r

@property
def circumference(self):
    return self._circumference

# if you wanted to allow setting (but you don't), you would add this:

#@circumference.setter
#def circumference(self, value):
#    self._circumference = value
```

`Computations` class is not needed at all.

### Better design

If you are going to have your own getter and setter for a calculated value, it makes sense that you calculate it on demand, without ever remembering the value:

```
@property
def circumference(self):
    return 2 * pi * self.r

# there is no self._circumference!
```

The benefit you get from this is that when `r` changes, circumference is still correct (with original code, `circumference` always has the original value from `__init__`).

### Note: This is Python 3!

It was not said explicitly before, so I say it here. This code works in Python 3.

If run with Python 2, the descriptors would be ignored because of the old-style class definition. To make the code work with Python 2, just make sure all classes inherit from `object`, e.g.

```
class Circle(object):
    ...
```

### Note 2: Type checking

Think twice before implementing type-checking in Python. **Not** checking for type usually makes the code better. In your case, you are limiting the values to integers, which means: float does not work, Decimal does not work, long does not work (in Python 2), MySpecialNumericType does not work. Although it would work if only the code did not explicitly forbid it.

Comment: In the test it's setting it to a float as an example, circle.circumference = 12 could also be a test example which should raise the error. So should I leave the code 'area = Computations('_area')' within the circle class since area is an attribute of circle?

Comment: Also, I just reused the __get__ from the Integer class since they would just be getting the value that's stored, unless since you're not actually setting the value of area, etc then it needs to behave differently?

Comment: I know I can use properties, I've already implemented the circle class using properties (which is far easier!), but I also need to implement it using descriptor classes (hence my dilemma).

Comment: Also, I'm not following your solution. Are you saying change the '__set__' to what you have above? Then you say make the attributes private, but where are you saying I should define them? In the Computations class (I did, but Computations has no attribute 'r' so that doesn't work), or are you saying put it in the Circle class?

Comment: @BrxttB Yes, __set__ goes to the computations class, where it already is. You should modify it as above